# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1/2} \cot(\pi x) \cos(2 \pi n x) dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1/2} \cot(\pi x) \cos(2 \pi n x) dx,$$

where $n$ is an integer.

I tried to use the integration by parts but the integral is getting only complicated with each step. Same observation using the property $\cos a \cos b = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(a − b) + \cos(a + b))$. Could you give me some hints? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral is divergent. Note that

$$\cot(\pi x)\cos(2\pi n x)\sim \frac{1}{\pi x}$$

for $x$ close to $0$.